# Posting from html

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html page. And when somebody accesses this page, I want  my page doing post to another place, get the answer, and include it into response.

For example, some user performs get to my page, my page doing post to news site, get response and include this response to its own response.

Is it any way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Of course there is. You need to make an AJAX request to a server which will send the data back to your page. I hate to say this, but this is one of the basic foundations of web programming.

Comment: If you going to access site on different domain, it's might be not that easy. They must support CORS or JSONP, and if they don't, browser will block any request to different domain. In this case only possible way is request to news site from server side

Comment: Ajax request are meant to be done within same domain, not to new site. Could you be more specific on this line *my page doing post to news site*

Comment: I tried to do this with ajax, but I get error :
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://techmvs.technion.ac.il:100/cics/WMN/wmnnut02. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @Matvey You can send Ajax request to local URL, which will parse external site from your server.

Answer (score 0):

Look up `XMLHttpRequest`. You basically have to do an HTTP request to the news site, get the response and place them in your document. That's it.

Comment: I tried to do this :
$.post( "http://techmvs.technion.ac.il:100/cics/WMN/wmnnut02", function( data ) {
 alert( "Success");
 });
But it does not work.
I got an error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://techmvs.technion.ac.il:100/cics/WMN/wmnnut02. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Are you editing the file locally? It has to be in a server. Put it in the locahost. Also make sure the link gives response correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's a basic thing in web development. i suggest you to use Jquery & Ajax

as you said, since you don't have answer providing site, so will get the answer from another site and post it back on your own page? find those sites (I assume those sites support this) use their paremeters to send the asnwer get them back by JSON Data post it back on your site by using result call back function within this JQuery Ajax method

Follow this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/ajax-jquery-post.htm) to get to know how to make JQuery Ajax

This is a JQuery Ajax function looks

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

and you need JQuery Framework for that [Download](http://jquery.com/download/)

Comment: I tried to do this with ajax, but I get error : XMLHttpRequest cannot load techmvs.technion.ac.il:100/cics/WMN/wmnnut02. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access

Comment: well, as i said, it depends upon the site you seek for the answer. not so difficult but tricky